# Install Chrome extension through windows registry

Tags: google-chrome-extension, registry

I want to install a Chrome extension through the Windows Registry, [as described in the documentation](https://chromeextensionsdocs.appspot.com/apps/external_extensions).

I have added the new registry key in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Wow6432node/Google/Chrome/Extensions/bbfbifchphidhgjegibafmlnbfpkmlik
```

Under this I added a new string key `"update_url":"https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx"` and `"version":"1.1.2"`, but on restarting Chrome, the new extension is not added in the Chrome extensions page. I am using Windows 7, 64-bit.

A [post on Google groups](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/eUb79HuMozE) lists a similar problem, but no resolution has been posted yet.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Chrome's [documentation on deployment options](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions) is very misleading. My problem was I set the `update_url` registry property explicitly to the JSON string specified in the documentation.

```
{
  "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx"
}
```

It should just be `https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx`, which makes a lot more sense.

Upon restarting Chrome entirely (if Chrome is allowed to run in the background, exit Chrome using the tray icon) a popup shows up asking whether the newly installed extension should be enabled or not.

This popup is only shown once. If it is ignored it does not show up next time. This behavior can be reset by adding and removing the application manually through the web store once, which seemingly resets some internal state stored by Chrome.

Comment: Right-click on your `key`. Select `New > String value`. Give it the Name `update_url` and the Value data `https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx`.
In Chrome, go to "chrome://extensions/". You should see the extension there instantly. (At least in my case I didn't have to restart Chrome.)