# Install Chrome extension through windows registry from chrome web store

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to install a Chrome extension through the Windows Registry.
I have added the new registry key like this.

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Wow6432node/Google/Chrome/Extensions/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc
```

under this I make two string values.

```
name            type          data
----------------------------------
update_url      REG_SZ        {"update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx"}
version         REG_SZ        0.0.32.2
```

And then I restart the chrome but no extension is installed why ?

I read a question on stackoverflow about this but I can't understand which value I set to `update_url`.
here is a [Question read it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735525/install-chrome-extension-through-windows-registry)
What I done wrong ?

For better understanding about registry key please see this image.

[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqAWE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [Alternative Extension Distribution Options](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions),

> On Windows and Mac, `update_URL` must point to the Chrome Web Store where the extension must be hosted.

More information and answers to frequently asked questions regarding external extensions can be found in [Alternative Extension Distribution Options](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions).

Answer (score 2):

update_url should be like this

```
name            type          data
----------------------------------
update_url      REG_SZ        https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx
```

Comment: wrapping up all above:
`reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Google\Chrome\Extensions\xxxxxxpaakbkfkmjjcbffibkxxxxx" /v update_url /t REG_SZ /d https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx`